# Using websocket connection inside job service (for Oreo+)

Tags: android, websocket, android-service, real-time, android-jobscheduler

Our project uses websocket connection to sync data.
Due to the limitations in Oreo, we aren't able to use service in background
We tried to move our websocket connection to a job service.
The service will be invoked by the system and job service will stay connected for about 30 sec and after job will reschedule.
But sometimes this won't work as expected
My question is: is using websocket with job service is a bad idea?
What are the alternate solutions?

Comment: what do you mean by "But sometimes this won't work as expected" ? What was expected and what happened ?